# Running a software (Python script with GUI) as soon as possible after boot

Tags: debian, x11, desktop, desktop-environment, kiosk

I'm working on an embedded computer, which will have no keyboard / no mouse, but only a touchscreen (a kiosk).

I would like to start, as soon as possible on boot, without any message / splash logo, and without a login prompt, the Python script with its GUI in fullscreen. (My Python script uses wxPython for GUI).

**How should I configure my Debian 8 or Ubuntu server for this?**

Should I use remove the existing desktop manager (probably Unity for Ubuntu?) 
Should I then install `nodm`, `lightdm` or something else?

Then I thought about creating a `systemd` service that would start my `python myscript.py`. Is that the correct way to go?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it. The simplest is to configure auto-login for your DE, and start your python script via `.xinitrc` or similar.

You should also be able to disable the DE and just put in `/etc/rc.local` some commands that start X and launch your python script.

Comment: Thanks. If I do it within a DE, there will probably be a flicker like DE desktop image, loading time, then after 500ms my software will show, don't you think so? With your solution #2, how to start X and launch Python script (the latter can be done with `python myscript.py`)? Can I start X without any DE?   Note: I'm using systemd and not init.

Comment: @Basj Ubuntu `systemd` has compatibility with `/etc/rc.local` so you don't need to fool around trying to add tasks to `systemd`. Of course there will be load time delays. You can at least make the screen back with `xsetroot` while the app loads.

Comment: Do you mean make the screen *black*? Do you think you can add some code in your answer for future reference, i.e. how to start X and launch Python?

Comment: @Basj Yeah, I know, everyone wants code, code, code. I could come up with a v0.1, but someone would come along and say "I tried that and it didn't work, you're wrong", downvotes etc. So I won't post code without proper testing, and this is the kind of thing that is very tedious to test properly.